# Mailchimp template columns being pushed to next row in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, css-tables

I'm designing a newsletter for a client using Mailchimp and then exporting the HTML (being sure to convert to inline CSS). I have a section that should be made up of two columns, but when viewing in Outlook, it comes out like this:

[image].....

What's going wrong here? Maybe it's a width issue, but I've been tinkering with the code for hours now and I haven't cracked it. I'm relatively new to this so any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

jsfiddle   /robjmoran/6350hr7d/2/

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the template with an original Mailchimp template, or did you just code the whole thing yourself? Maybe you could give some code as well?

Comment: It's a Mailchimp template, the code is linked at the jsfiddle URL in my original post, but you'll have to add the .com as StackOverflow doesn't allow me to actually post it.